# How can I calculate $\mathbb{E}(X^{T}AX)$ supposed that the X is a random variable with known mean $\mu$ and variance $\mathcal{S}$

Tags: probability

Recently I was reading a paper in which there is a equation goes$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left\{g_k^e\right\}:= & \sum_{i=k-s_k+1}^k \mathbb{E}\left\{\left(\xi_i-y_i\right)^T \mathcal{P}^{-1}\left(\xi_i-y_i\right)\right\} \\
& +2 \sum_{i=k-s_k+1}^k \mathbb{E}\left\{\left(y_i-C \hat{x}_{i \mid i-1}\right)^T \mathcal{P}^{-1}\left(\xi_i-y_i\right)\right\} \\
& =\sum_{i=k-s_k+1}^k \mathbb{E}\left\{\xi_i^T \mathcal{P}^{-1} \xi_i-y_i^T \mathcal{P}^{-1} y_i+2\left(C \hat{x}_{i \mid i-1}\right)^T \mathcal{P}^{-1} y_i-2\left(C \hat{x}_{i \mid i-1}\right)^T \mathcal{P}^{-1} \xi_i\right\} \\
& =s_k \operatorname{Trace}\left(\mathcal{S} \circ \mathcal{P}^{-1}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $\xi_i$ follows the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(y_{i},\mathcal{S})$

So I am eager to know how to calculate the expectation of $x^TAx$ and Why there is a Hardamard product ***$Trace(\mathcal{S}\circ\mathcal{P^{-1}})$*** instead of product ***$Trace(\mathcal{S}\mathcal{P^{-1}})$*** showing in the results.